# track snack bar notificiations using google tag manager in an angular app

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angular-material, google-tag-manager

I created element visibility trigger in google tag manager to track angular material snack bar notifications. But the problem is, GTag needs it's reference on the page before it first loaded on page. But this notification element is not available on DOM since it's angular (8) single page application. only head, body tags and app-root tags are available on initial load. Only on doing some action on UI, we get these snack bar notifications. so the google tag manager - trigger is never fired. How to solve this?

[image: Trigger]

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your element visibility trigger? GTM visibility triggers should work for SPAs as well. I am wondering if it is just a configuration or selection issue.

Comment: @XTOTHELUpdated my question with screenshot of the trigger. When I enable preview mode and see debugger for the Tag associated to this trigger, Referrer is matching but element is not recognized. I have the class snack-error on my element I'm trying to track. I tried giving it a id. but that did not work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Element Visibility trigger](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679410?hl=en) for SPAs and elements that are not present at load, you need to check the "Observe DOM Changes" checkbox.

Comment: Is there a way to track when 2 different elements are visible on screen?

Comment: Yes, use a comma, just like you would with CSS rules.

Comment: I used comma but the trigger is firing when it found element matching first css selector. Not waiting until the 2nd css selector. I want the trigger to fire only when both css selectors are present on view port.

Comment: Create a visibility trigger for each and add them to a trigger group, then set the trigger to that trigger group for the tag. https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9164222?hl=en

Comment: I already tried trigger group but it will not solve the problem because, trigger group will fire when all the triggers in it fired at least once. Say for example, if I add 2 triggers to a trigger group and reference a tag to it The tag will be fired even if those 2 triggers in trigger-group fire at 2 different times. What I'm interested in is: Raise event only when those 2 elements are present at once on the view port.

Comment: haha...ok so I think what would work is...create a visibility VARIABLE for one element, then for the event tag, add in the visibility TRIGGER for the OTHER element and then add in the condition that the VARIABLE for the first element must also be "True".